# if $f\in C_c(X)$, then $f$ is zero on boundary of $supp(f)$

Tags: general-topology

if $X$ be a topological space and $f\in C_c(X)$, then we know that $$f\bigg[\Big(supp(f)\Big)^c\bigg]=0 $$

> is this true that if $f\in C_c(X)$, then $f\bigg[\partial\Big(supp(f)\Big)\bigg]=0$?

if $x\in \partial \Big(supp(f)\Big) $, since $$\partial \Big(supp(f)\Big)\subseteq\overline{ \Big(supp(f)\Big)^c } $$ there exist a net $\{x_{\alpha}\}\subseteq \Big(supp(f)\Big)^c $ such that $x_{\alpha}\longrightarrow x$ and since $f$ is continous, then $$0= f(x_{\alpha})\longrightarrow f(x)$$

it implies that $f(x)=0$.

is my proof true?

Comment: Yes, it is a valid proof.

Answer (score 1):

It works with nice topological spaces which are sequentiable (like metric spaces for example). If you want a more general proof involving pure topological reasoning with open and closed set, recall that by definition, when $A \subset X$, $\overline{A}$ is the smallest (for the inclusion) closed subset that containes $A$, $\overset{\mathrm{o}}{A}$ is the largest open subset contained in $A$ and $\partial A = \overline{A}\backslash\overset{\mathrm{o}}{A}$.

And $\mathrm{supp}(f) = \overline{f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*)}$, and continuity of $f$ means that the reciprocal image of open (or equivalently closed) subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is open in $X$. In particular, $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*)$ is open in $X$. In particular, it equals its own interior thus $\overset{\mathrm{o}}{\overline{f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*)}} \supset \overset{\mathrm{o}}{f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*)} = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*)$.

From here, we have that,
$$
f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*) \cap \partial\mathrm{supp}(f) = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*) \cap \left(\overline{f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*)}\backslash \overset{\mathrm{o}}{\overline{f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*)}}\right) \subset f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*)\backslash f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*) = \emptyset.
$$
It proves that for all $x \in \partial\mathrm{supp}(f)$, $x \notin f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*)$ hence $f(x) = 0$ without using sequence.

Comment: Those are nets not sequences

Comment: Ok, I was disturbed by the notations.